# Group by a field inside a nested query

Tags: mysql

We have a nested sql query we want to group  by a field that is into a nested query rather than grouping by a field that is on the main query .

```
SELECT dataissue.value as a,
    COUNT(value),
    substring(issue.entry, 1, 3) 
FROM DataIssue, issue 
WHERE field = 'point_d_effort' 
  AND dataissue.issue = issue.id  

  AND issue IN (
         SELECT issue
         FROM dataissue, issue 
         WHERE dataissue.issue = issue.id 
           AND value = 'récit' 
           AND substring(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema'
  ) 
  AND issue IN (
         SELECT issue 
         FROM dataissue, issue 
         WHERE dataissue.issue = issue.id 
           AND value = 'Fermée' 
           AND substring(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' 
 ) 

 AND issue IN (
         SELECT issue 
         FROM   dataissue, issue 
         WHERE  dataissue.issue = issue.id 
         AND    field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)' AS b 
         AND    substring(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' 
 ) 

GROUP BY dataissue.value as b
```

To sumarize:  The group by uses the field `value alias a`  inside the main query `WHERE field = 'point_d_effort'`. However, I want to group by the field `( value alias  b )` inside the nested query  `WHERE field = 'Version(s)_corrigée(s)'`.

How may I do that? Thank you.

For more precisions ,

Hi all first of all , i want to thank you  for contributing to the answer  here is an SQL fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/610e7/1

-- This query will return all the attributes of an issue

`select * from dataissue where issue  = '25998'`  .

What I want to  have is  :

```
sum(value) count(value)    

where field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)'

and value  = 'Fermée' 

and  field = 'point_d_effort'

and value = 'récit'

and group it by value where field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)'
```

Comment: Could you provide a mock table and set of data as well as an example of the results?

Comment: also does it currently work or is this a stub of an attempt, also what does "from DataIssue,issue" mean, note the comma

Comment: It is an alternative type of join

Comment: old style a decade or more ago i think

Comment: This is not good. Bin it, and start over. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry imagine the table scans on this with the multi correlated and the substrings

Comment: @DrewPierce Thanks - I prefer not too!

Comment: What does it mean by "AND field = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)' AS b "? Is this allowed "GROUP BY dataissue.value as b"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
SELECT  main2.value AS VALUE,nbreticket,ticket FROM 
(
SELECT dataissue.issue,dataissue.value,COUNT(VALUE) AS nbreticket,SUM(VALUE) AS ticket,SUBSTRING(issue.entry,1,3) ,FIELD
FROM DataIssue,issue WHERE  dataissue.issue = issue.id  AND VALUE IS NOT NULL AND FIELD = 'point_d_effort' AND issue IN ( SELECT issue
FROM dataissue,issue WHERE dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE = 'récit' 
AND SUBSTRING(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' ) AND issue IN ( SELECT issue 
FROM dataissue,issue WHERE dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE = 'Fermée' 
AND SUBSTRING(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' ) AND issue IN ( SELECT issue 
FROM dataissue,issue WHERE dataissue.issue = issue.id 
AND FIELD = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)' AND SUBSTRING(issue.entry,1,3) = 'ema' ) 
GROUP BY dataissue.value, issue

) main1 JOIN
(
SELECT  issue, `value` FROM DataIssue  WHERE  
FIELD = 'version(s)_corrigée(s)' 

)main2
WHERE main1.issue = main2.issue
GROUP BY main2.value
```

In your sql GROUP BY clause has alias name, we can't do alias name for group clause.

Again in where condition has alias name, we can't do alias name for where clause also.

In your sql some syntax error is there. I cleared all errors now sql is running  fine.

Thank you.

Comment: I know its just so you understaand the query i put the aliases . now you havent seen what i want in the second part  the sum and the count with thos criteria grouped by that field (versionscorrigees)

Comment: can you provide sample result? here field column has string datatype, You can do count of that column, we can't do sum of that column.

Comment: of course here is a sample :                                                                                                     http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/610e7/3                                                                             and with sum value :                                                                                            http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/610e7/28                                                                            its like we will group a field by another field inside the same table using the criteria in the where